# How to split my screen into three parts with different text content in React native

Tags: react-native

I am working on a React native project, In this I have one doubt can someone please tell me how To split the screen into three parts with different content using react native.
This is what I tried so someone please tell me how to achieve another two parts

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const App = props => {
  return (
    <View
      style={[
        {flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'},
        {justifyContent: 'space-around'},
        styles.container,
      ]}>
      <Text>Mark</Text>
      <Text style={[{backgroundColor: 'green'}]}>Tom</Text>
      <Text style={[{backgroundColor: 'red'}]}>Williams</Text>
      <Text>Sara</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 10,
    padding: 10,
    color: '#ff0000',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate three parts ?

Comment: Hi @GuruparanGiritharan from my above code I have written four names using Text component in View component. like that I have to write another four names under first four names list so please tell me how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have components inside components just like the above code, You just have to Wrap it inside another parent view, you can add any number of views like that.
Something like below, Also i put your styles in a proper way to make it clear.

```
const App = props => {
  return (
   <View>

     <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Mark</Text>
      <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>Tom</Text>
      <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>Williams</Text>
      <Text>Sara</Text>
    </View>

     <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Mark</Text>
      <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>Tom</Text>
      <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>Williams</Text>
      <Text>Sara</Text>
    </View>

     <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Mark</Text>
      <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>Tom</Text>
      <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>Williams</Text>
      <Text>Sara</Text>
    </View>

   </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 10,
    padding: 10,
    color: '#ff0000',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    flex:1
  },
});
```